# In .net, what's the best / safest way to add a "end of line" character to a text file?

Tags: .net, text-files

I assume there must be a system and language independent way to just stick the "current" EOL character into a text file, but my MSDN-fu seems to be weak today.  Bonus points if there is a way to do this in a web application that will put the correct EOL character for the current client's machine's OS, not the web server's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bonus point:

- Check the user-agent of the client machine, for substrings such as Windows, or Linux
- The System.Environment.NewLine for Windows is 0x13, 0x10; in unix, it's generally 0x10 only;
- Choose the appropriate newline string, append it to the line, and off you go

Answer (score 2):

[System.Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Open the text file, seek to the end, and append Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Environment.NewLine`.  This will only be for your current operating system however.

Answer (score 1):

For server-side code I would go for [TextWriter.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebb1kw70.aspx). Detecting the OS of the  client's machine requires [browser sniffing](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120402-1.aspx) - check Request.Browser.